# Android: open video picker and filter videos seen by length

Tags: java, android, video, picker

This is my code for opening up the picker for Videos and Images - however I need to not show Videos that are longer than 5 minutes in length. Is this possible?

```
 public void startChoosePhotoFromLibrary() {
        if (checkOrRequestExternalStoreagePermission()) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
                Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                photoPickerIntent.setType("image/* video/*");
                startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, PICK_PHOTO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
            } else {
                Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                photoPickerIntent.setType("*/*");
                photoPickerIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, new String[]{"image/*", "video/*"});
                startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, PICK_PHOTO_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is my code for opening up the picker for Videos and Images

`ACTION_PICK` does not use MIME types. `ACTION_PICK` picks from a collection of content, where that collection is identified by the `Uri` that you supply in the `Intent`.

Also, MIME types do not have spaces in them.

> Is this possible?

Not via those `Intent` actions, or via any content-selection mechanism that is part of the Android SDK.

You are welcome to query the `MediaStore` for videos, and there may be a way to filter such videos by length. But then you would need to present your own UI for allowing the user to choose something from the query results (e.g., `ListView`, `RecyclerView`).

Comment: Thanks I figured this was the only option